# How to get all values of an object in ActiveRecord in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rails-activerecord

One can use `column_names` to get all the columns of a table, but what if one would like to know all the values of a particular instance in ActiveRecord.

For example,

```
User.column_names
=> ["id", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "tel", "interests", "admin_status", "created_at", "updated_at", "city_id", "profile_image_file_name", "profile_image_content_type", "profile_image_file_size", "profile_image_updated_at"]

User.first
=> #<User id: 1, email: "aatir@jpl.com", tel: "+923223333333", interests: "Hi, I'm interested in coding.", admin_status: "download", created_at: "2016-08-16 22:38:05", updated_at: "2016-08-16 22:38:05", city_id: 2, profile_image_file_name: "Screen_Shot_2016-07-02_at_4.41.32_PM.png", profile_image_content_type: "image/png", profile_image_file_size: 324372, profile_image_updated_at: "2016-08-16 22:38:04">
```

When `first` method is called, it returns key-value pairs. What I want is to have only values, is there a single method in ActiveRecord that can do this for us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm extending @deepak's answer to assure that the order remains same as it is for `column_names`, and this is how, I achieved it:

```
User.first.attributes.values_at *User.column_names
```

To get just the values, irrespective of the order:

```
User.first.attributes.values
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also use `attributes` method to get it

```
User.first.attributes.values
```

1. `User.first.attributes` will return you hash representation of `user` object

   ```
   User.first.attributes

   { 
     "id" => 1,
     "email" => "aatir@jpl.com",
     "tel" => "+923223333333",
     "interests" => "Hi, I'm interested in coding.",
     "admin_status" => "download",
     "created_at" => "2016-08-16 22:38:05",
     "updated_at" => "2016-08-16 22:38:05",
     "city_id" => 2,
     "profile_image_file_name" => "Screen_Shot_2016-07-02_at_4.41.32_PM.png",
     "profile_image_content_type" => "image/png",
     "profile_image_file_size" => 324372,
     "profile_image_updated_at" => "2016-08-16 22:38:04"
   }
   ```
2. `values` will return you the values in the `Array`

   ```
   User.first.attributes.values

   [1, "aatir@jpl.com", "+923223333333", "Hi, I'm interested in coding.", "download", "2016-08-16 22:38:05", "2016-08-16 22:38:05", 2, "Screen_Shot_2016-07-02_at_4.41.32_PM.png", "image/png", 324372, "2016-08-16 22:38:04"]
   ```

Comment: I deleted my answer in favour of yours. But I am not sure if the `values` version is helpful, because the order of the attributes is not guaranteed in the `attributes` hash. Without a fixed, deterministic order in the hash you cannot be sure about the order of the values in the array. That would make it hard to actually read attributes from that array later on.

Comment: @spickermann In a way it is deterministic. Since ruby 1.9 values are returned in the same order as they have been added to the hash. I think it's relativ save (but not guaranteed) to asume that within Rails every attribute is added in the same order to the attributes Hash every time.

Comment: That depends probably on the database engine unless Rails orders the column names before adding the values to the attributes hash. Since MySQL for example doesn't guarantee any order (unless you specify an order ourself) I would doubt that the result is deterministic.

Answer (score 2):

Just you can convert activerecord to Hash then get the values as the following:

```
User.first.as_json.values
```

Comment: You should wait about 10 mins :D ... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.first.attributes.values
```